# Building glog: force libtool to use c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to build Google's glog on a SUSE machine.  I do a 'configure' then a 'make'.  The 'make' fails right out of the gates.  Why?  Not sure, but libtool is doing something like 'libtool --mode=compile CC'.  This generates compiler errors.  If I did something else like   'libtool --mode=compile c++', the compiler errors go away.

Question: how can I force the build scripts/tools to use c++ instead of CC?

UPDATE: I reconfigured with 'configure CXX=c++' and it compiled successfully.

Question: Should I have known to do this from the start? Is this a common thing that people must do to compile 3rd party source?

Comment: The `configure --help` may answer your questions...

Comment: Yes, 'configure --help' would have probably helped.  Is there a way to know what the default values are for things like CC and CXX?

Comment: The `configure` in general produces the `config.status` file. Run the `configure` without parameters and see the `config.status`. Plus nobody prohibit to see the `configure` itself -- it is a shell script (thus a big one, but you may found a lot of needed stuff in its content...).